# Assign string from vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector, assign

```
vector<string> a;
string b;
a.push_back("1");
a.push_back("2");
b = a.back();
```

I would like to assign string `b` to a value from the vector of strings.

`b = a.back()` does not seem to work. `b.assign(a.at(1))` does not seem to work.

Is there any way I can do this? gdb says there is error at `raise.c:54`.

Comment: How did you verify that `b = a.back();` doesn't work? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56460bc0e3b818f0

Comment: `b = a.back()` *and* `b.assign(a.at(1))` work just fine. Could you post a [mcve] that demonstrates how they don't?

Comment: Cannot reproduce; `b` contains `"2"` in my test.

Comment: If we can't see line 54, we can't comment on the error at line 54.

Comment: If the error is in `raise.c`, are you sure that your code is compiled as C++ and not in language C?

Comment: Can you provide a backtrace from the gdb at the time you get the error?

Comment: Thank you for your comments!!! I will look further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to assign string b to a value from the vector of strings.

The way to do it is exactly like in your code. Either version is correct.

If this program crashes, then possibly your compiler / runtime library is borked. You could try to solve that by reinstalling a fresh copy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try reinstalling!